# Press and hold arrow keys doesn't advance cursor in Firefox

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, firefox

It's a few weeks that when I am in a field text in Firefox (gmail, discourse forums and others, but e.g. not here in AskUbuntu) if I keep pressed the right/left arrows, the cursor does not advance on the text. To advance of, say, 10 chars, I need to press the arrow 10 times instead of just keeping it pressed. Same for the "del" command.
I have disabled all the extensions.
What the hell could be? Or how to google it (no luck) ?

[EDIT]:
According to a thread in reddit, this is a Firefox bug that should have been already fixed for the next release of Firefox: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/1bkitla/keyboard_key_repeat_not_working_only_in_firefox/
I just hope that it will be backported to Ubutnu 22.04 users...

Comment: please read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly. As it stands, it's difficult to see what your issue is.

Comment: I understand perfectly well what the problem is, but I have no solution. Two questions: how did you install Firefox (snap or apt)? Did you try disabling hardware acceleration in Firefox (Settings/General/scroll down to close to the bottom)?

Comment: Thanks @Jos It's APT, but I don't have that setting. Also, I don't understand the negative mark to the question. On reddit they pointed me to [bug 1880619](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1880619), but I am not sure...

Comment: Are you sure you don't have that setting? It's been around for a long while. [Here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/performance-settings) is a Mozilla article about how to find the setting. The bug you link to doesn't seem relevant at all.